# Resolving a Git merge conflict in favour of ours or theirs without taking the whole file from either

Tags: git, version-control

There are numerous questions on Stack Overflow on how to resolve merge conflicts in favour of one or the other branch. But the most common answer I'm finding is using `git checkout --ours` or `git checkout --theirs`.

The problem is `git checkout` will take the *entire* file from either branch. There could've been parts of the file that merged just fine, and we don't want them removed.

Given a file in a conflicted state, is there a way to remove the conflict markers in favour of "ours" or "theirs" **without** applying this strategy to the entire merge or taking the entire file from "ours" or "theirs"?

This is definitely possible with a simple script, but I want to know if there's an existing solution I'm not finding.

Comment: You *do not* need to choose an entire file's 'ours' or 'theirs'. In fact, it's a fairly rare case. Any half-decent differ will do that for you. https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line

Comment: @msanford I don't understand the connection of your comment to my question. I want a fast, automated way of resolving conflicts in an individual file by taking one branches changes _in cases of conflict_.

Comment: So you want this done for all remaining conflicts, right?  Resolve all remaning conflicts as if you'd specified `-X ours` or theirs on the original merge?

Comment: ... and by "this is definitely possible with a simple script" do you mean you've already found `git merge-index` and `git-merge-one-file`?

Comment: @jthill yes, but I want that for an individual file. I had not heard of the git tools you mentioned. Will check them out.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to resolve all remaining conflicts in a file to ours or theirs it's a straightforward `sed` per side you want and your conflict style.

For most code files, where the conflict markers are so foreign that you don't have to be careful about identifying them, it's so easy you can just type it:

```bash
sed -si '/^<<</,/^>>>/ {/^<<</,/^===/d;/^>>>/d}' thefile  # keep theirs
sed -si '/^<<</,/^>>>/ {/^<<</d;/^===/,/^>>>/d}' thefile  # keep ours
```

And to do that for everything,

```bash
sed -si $yourpattern $(git ls-files -m | uniq)
```

is easiest.

To be more careful with your conflict markers, it's better to make the simple script you referred to, and the [diff3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff3) conflict-reporting style needs some changes as well.  The usual conflict symbol count is 7, and for best safety make your sed range `/^<<<<<<< ours$/,/^>>>>>>> theirs$/`, and with diff3 reporting the "keep ours" deletion range starts with `^||||||| base$`, not `^=======$`.

`sed` on the Mac has been butchered to refuse to do inline edits without creating a backup file. You have to do e.g. `-si.bak` and then delete the backup.

Comment: Can we do also: `grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . | xargs sed -si $yourpattern`? since `$(git ls-files -m | uniq)` does not cover all the conflicted files

Comment: @alper Yes, you can do that, but `git ls-files -m` does cover all conflicted files, any markers it doesn't find were added as tests or bad puns or by mistake as a correct resolution -- and not necessarily for this merge.

Comment: To be safe could I apply both ?

Answer (score 1):

As [Marcus notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962141/resolving-a-git-merge-conflict-in-favour-of-ours-or-theirs-without-taking-the-wh#comment98580406_55962336), `git mergetool` can be invoked on a single file.  With the right `merge.tool` or `-t` argument and `mergetool.<tool>.cmd` setting, you can make it invoke a tiny script that:

- puts the `--ours` version of the file into the work-tree copy, then
- uses that plus the base and `--theirs` versions of the file as the arguments to `git merge-file --ours` or `git merge-file --theirs`.

The exit code of this "editor" can be trusted (see `merge.<tool>.trustExitCode`) which allows `git mergetool` to run `git add` for you.  So you can probably shorten the script somewhat.

(I never do this, and in fact I never use `git mergetool` either.  If I *were* using `git mergetool` I'd want to eyeball the results myself, as [Marcus suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55964729/1256452).)

---

There isn't a one-line command to do this, though there probably should be *and* you can script it yourself.

The command that will do the job is `git merge-file`.  Before you can *run* `git merge-file`, though, you need the three input files that `git merge` saw.

Those three files *do exist;* the problem lies in extracting them.  The `git mergetool` command solves this problem,<sup>1</sup> but unfortunately, it solves it in a way that's not particularly useful to you.  You want to solve it for *one file* but `git mergetool` repeats it for *all unmerged files* (and then runs your chosen merge tool, usually some sort of three-way editor, on them, one at a time).

What `git mergetool` does is use `git checkout-index` with the `--stage` option.  The three versions of some file *`file.ext`* are all in the *index*, as stage 1 (merge base version), stage 2 (`--ours` version), and stage 3 (`--theirs` version).  When using `git mergetool`, the script extracts the three into `file.ext.BASE`, `file.ext.LOCAL`, and `file.ext.REMOTE` respectively.  You must do more or less the same thing, though you might want to choose different names.  See [the `git mergetool` script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6/git-mergetool.sh#L304-L306) (and, if you like, its main [helper script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool--lib.sh), though all you need here is the main one—I've linked directly to the lines that extract the files, while the function that implements that is elsewhere in the main file) for the code.

Once you have the three input files, simply run `git merge-file` on them, with the correct arguments.  See [the `git merge-file` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) to see what those arguments are.  Inspect the result, and if you like, put it into place instead of the existing conflicts-marked-up work-tree file and use `git add` to eliminate the three higher-stage-number files and write the merged file into stage zero, where it's ready for committing.

Resolve the remaining unresolved files however you like.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, that is, it solves it for most cases.  For rename/rename conflicts, `git mergetool` just gets confused: the information in the index is a little bit lacking here.

Comment: git mergetool accepts file parameters. Simply run "git mergetool -- path/to/file".

Comment: @Marcus: aha, so it does. (I never actually *use* the thing!) This simplifies the job a lot, since you can have `git mergetool` run `git merge-file` for you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't work this way. Instead, you should install a suitable merge editor ([KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), for example), run `git mergetool` (which iterates over the files in conflict and runs the installed merge editor) and review the changes manually.

The merge tool will open the three versions of the file in conflict, will automatically take all solvable changes just as you wished, and will highlight remaining conflicts. If you really don't want to review them one-by-one, select menu item *Merge* → *Choose xxx for each unresolved conflict*, and tadah.

If you are really sure you don't want to use a visual merge tool, you have the following options beneath the one [mentioned by torek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962141/resolving-a-git-merge-conflict-in-favour-of-ours-or-theirs-without-taking-the-wh/55962336#55962336).

If you want to apply this strategy to *each conflicted file* during one merge, use the "ours" or "theirs" suboption to the standard merge strategy:

```
git merge -Xours ...
```

*Don't confuse it with selecting the whole merge strategy with `-s ours`*, which simply takes everything from ours without trying to do a merge.

If you want to apply this strategy to *some particular files* during *every merge*, you can define a custom merge driver (in .gitconfig) and apply it to that files (in .gitattributes). This sounds much more complicated than it is. Defining a merge driver simply means to define a command line which takes three input files and creates one output file, you can for example use git merge-file as torek explained it. Once defined, you can assign such a merge driver to any file or pattern by creating a .gitattributes file in the repository root and committing it. Just read about it on *[gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)*.